Is it Possible to Define the Price of Stability (PoS) for a Game with Only One Nash Equilibrium?
I have a question regarding the concept of the price of stability (PoS) in game theory. The PoS is typically defined as the ratio of the cost (or utility) of the best Nash equilibrium to the cost (or utility) of the social optimum:
$$ \text{PoS} = \frac{\text{Cost (or utility) of the best Nash equilibrium}}{\text{Cost (or utility) of the social optimum}} $$
This makes sense in games where there are multiple equilibria, allowing us to choose the best one for the calculation. However, I am wondering how this concept applies in the case of a game that has only one Nash equilibrium.
Specifically, my questions are:

Can the price of stability be defined in a meaningful way for a game with a single Nash equilibrium?
If so, how would it be calculated and interpreted?

Thank you in advance!

If there is a single Nash equilibrium, it must be the best.
